# Is there a way to generate pdf in order based on the XML code when using xsl:apply-template and xsl:call-template?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I'm currently generating a multiple page PDF document in Java using XML code and XSLT.

The XML is generated in the same order of the Input (which is what I want).

However, when generating the PDF I run into an organization issue.

Because of multiple Stylesheets being called using call-template and apply-template, It generates the PDF in the order of my apply-template categories.

To explain this better here is a simplified example:

```
Input:            
cheese
milk
bread
bagels
rice
eggs
```

Given this input, I generate XML matching the order.

```
<food>
      <dairy>
          <cheese>
                   <.....></>   <---------cheese information
                   <.....></>    <---------etc.
          </cheese>
     </dairy>



      <grains>
          <bread>
                   <.....></>    <---------bread information
                   <.....></>    <---------etc.
          </bread>
     </grains>
 </food>
```

The XML code is then used by the Stylesheet to Generate a PDF in the following way

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/food/dairy"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="/food/grains"/>

<xsl:template match="/food/dairy">
      <xsl:call-template name="dairy"></xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/food/grains">
      <xsl:call-template name="grains"></xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Now what Is happening is we get eggs jumping grains and following cheese and milk instead of staying in the same order.

Is there a way to maintain the XML order when calling and applying templates?

I've only been able to find this relevant post: [Apply XSLT template respecting the order in the XML-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39510333/apply-xslt-template-respecting-the-order-in-the-xml-source)

Although it doesn't quite match my problem.

Comment: *"we get eggs jumping grains and following cheese and milk instead of staying in the same order."* I don't see why that would happen in the given example.

Comment: I'm not too sure why either. I think my issue really just stems from my lack of understanding of apply-templates and call-templates. it loops through all of dairy matching anything that fits and then moves on to grains. I just want it to check at every level and apply the template not loop through for every template

Comment: We need a better example, including the XML (see: [mcve]).

Comment: You've actually already solved my issue. It seems that it was as simple as having only one apply template with many ORs instead of our many apply templates. Sorry for the lack of/ incorrect information in my question and thank you for your help.

Comment: The `|` is actually a *union* operator, not an *OR*. Note that there are other ways to select multiple "branches" of the tree as a single node-set.

Comment: Oh ok, Both XML and XSLT are new to me so my java background might be shaping how I look at things. So i'm just merging them all essentially?

Comment: I prefer the technical term [union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)). See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256074(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I appreciate the help. The site you sent was really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find your question rather confusing. In your example, templates matching `dairy` are applied before templates matching `grains`. To prevent this and keep the document order, you should replace:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/food/dairy"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="/food/grains"/>
```

with:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/food/dairy | /food/grains"/>
```

---

Of course, this is a completely bogus example - if only because an XML document cannot have two root elements.